# Strange error for member function declaration

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Below is something that did happen to me and I couldn't get what's wrong. My coworker and me screwed our heads around this. It was in a cross-platform library using the cross-platform toolkit wxWidgets on Windows

```
#include <wx/wx.h> 

class Graph {
public:
  // ...
  // main1.cpp:4:10: error: expected identifier before '(' token
  double GetYValue(double x);
};
```

We were trying hard to find any weird glyph placed instead of an ASCII `e` or something, but didn't find any such issue. What was going on!?

Comment: Is `GetYValue` a macro somewhere?

Comment: Looks like it's probably a macro replacement that's altering the `GetYValue` text (or something just before it) but I don't know enough about wxWidgets to guess what it might be. Did you check what that line looks like after preprocessing?

Comment: It's odd to see you asking a question like this, usually you're the one answering them!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WinGDI.h ln 640: `#define GetYValue(cmyk)      ((BYTE)((cmyk)>> 8))`

Gotta love windows.h

This is why I recommend AGAINST using camel case for most things.

Comment: But most (every one I have read) standards say use all upper case for MACROS. Thus my advice is don't make macros that are not all uppercase and don't make functions that are all uppercase.

Comment: Yeah haha this was the issue xD http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372091%28VS.85%29.aspx silly windows.h ...

Comment: Yeah, `<windows.h>` is a pest. It pollutes thousands of common identifiers as macros. That header best confined to a few `.cpp` files only. And wxWidgets just drags it in everywhere, so the same advice applies. Or just drop CamelCase altogether in favour of the std_lib_convention (whatever that's named). The C++ std lib is much less polluting.

Comment: And that's not the only thing wxWidgets gets wrong.  Still though, decent library for what it does...for the most part.

Comment: I've given up on wxWidgets since Qt became LGPL :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't use wxWidgets myself, but in http://gambit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.2006.01.20/plotctrl_8cpp-source.html I find strange code fragment

```
#ifdef GetYValue   // Visual Studio 7 defines this
    #undef GetYValue
#endif
```

Look at the wxWidgets headers. Probably are there a code fragment like this or you should do something like this?

Answer (score 6):

My first guess would be that `<wx/wx.h>` has a macro named `GetYValue` (and probably another named `GetXValue`) that are supposed to take some sort of combined X/Y value and "unwrap" them into their individual components, on the general order of:

```
#define GetXValue(xy) ((xy)>>16)
#define GetYValue(xy) ((xy)&x0ff)
```

With that expanded, your code would look something like:

```
double ((xy)>>16)(double x);
```

...at which point the compiler has a hissy fit -- except, of course, that it probably gave up parsing sooner than that, since the `double x` appears to be trying pass two tokens as parameters to a macro that only expects 1.

Edit: I see I was guessing fairly close, but guessed wrong about what sort of "Y" was involved here -- the others would apparently be `GetCValue`, `GetMValue`, etc., instead of `GetXValue`. Oh well...

Comment: +1 nice explanations all around. Wasn't sure what i'm going to accept. Such a hard decision!